# Layout for a thesis chapter describing an undergraduate course

Tags: thesis, writing, writing-style, coursework

I am writing a chapter in my degree thesis which describes a new undergraduate course I designed. I want to be as specific as possible with this course, like outlining what topic should be covered in each class. It is the main chapter of my thesis. Things that I am sure I must include are the learning objectives, the syllabus and a mention to the  instructional strategy (which in this case will be Flipped classroom).

How would you go about structuring this chapter? What things about the course should I include and in what order?

Can someone link me to a paper describing a new course in detail? It would be useful to have a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of theses depends very much on the standards of individual programs & institutions.  Your best bet would be to get a copy of a previous year's thesis in your program from your institution's library (they always keep them all).  Find one that has done something similar to what you are doing and use a similar structure (and, of course, if you refer to anything in it, cite & reference it appropriately).

For your reference, here's a [general new course description](http://mekki.ca/Sample%20course%20description%20.pdf) that I developed for one of my courses.  Its format is heavily based on the standards of the university, so may not apply to your particular situation.